# sql query to sum over deltas in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, linked-list

I have incoming sensor data that is stored in a table. Each record for a sensor has few "counter" columns. Counters are nothing but a snapshot in time. example records are shown below.

```
|id    | sensor  | counter 1  | counter 2  | timestamp
  1        5          100         200        10:00 AM
  2        5          125         210        10:01 AM
...
  60       5          1000        800        11:00 AM
```

I have thousands of such sensors sending snapshots of their counter values in time. What i need to do is, given a time period say between 10 am and 11 am, map the **delta** between records to a chart. Delta is always taken to the previous record.
What is the SQL query to get the delta's between consecutive records?
Second question I have is, what is a good table design to store such data which is self-referencing. Probably as a linked list with each record pointing to the previous record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic SQL is:

```
select t.*,
       (select counter1 from t t2 where t2.sensor = t.sensor and t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
        order by timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) prevCounter1
from t
```

The `limit 1` depends on the database.  It might be `top 1` (SQL Server, Sybase) or `where rownum = 1` (Oracle).

You need to do this for each counter.

If you are using Postgres, Oracle, or SQL Server 2012, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(counter1) over (partition by sensor order by timestamp) as prevCounter1
from t
```

In MySQL, you will be best off if you put in a `prevID`.  If not, an index on `sensor, timestamp` should give you reasonable performance.

Comment: Since this table will have potentially millions of records, wouldn't order by timestamp be a killer?

Comment: @Abe . . . I'm not aware that you have a choice, given your table design.  If you have a `prevId` column, then you can do a simple join to get the previous value.

Comment: You are telling that considering the requirement, the choice to have prevId column is not a bad idea right? b.t.w the query you provided doesnt really get the delta, is is just a matter of doing counter1Alias1 - counter1Alias2. Apologize if its basic q, am pretty much newb in sql.

Comment: @Abe . . . The query was meant to give you an idea of what to do.  Because the formulation depends on the database (which is not tagged), you would probably have to rework it anyway.  You can replace `counter1` in the example with `id` to get the previous id, and then join in the values that you want.  And, having a `prevId` column is a good idea if you need to support this type of query and you can keep it up-to-date.

Comment: @Abe, the solution to a table with lots of records is a where clause.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, probably I need to have a window using "between" clause for the timestamp to make it work for very large number of records.

Comment: Actually, for timestamps, >= StartDateTime and < EndStartDateTime plus one second is better than using between.